# Worpress hyperlink change color to white

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot change my hyperlink color it is already black. I want to change it to white, go and check the [web](https://kastratihome.com) footer and you will see phone numbers appear in black color.

Code1:

```
p.text hover {
    color:white;
}
```

Code2:

```
p.text:link {
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Add !important end of css line before ;

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. All code relevant to your problem needs to be contained directly inside your question - _do not_ just link to external sites.

Comment: Wich one is okay from my code. to add that !important  ??

Answer (score 1):

Go to Dashboard -> Apperance ->customize->Additional CSS

add this code`a:link { color: #ffffff !important; }`

The reason you color is not changing is because you are applying style to`<p>` tag but for hyperlink you have to target `<a>` tag .